# What do you call a person who does average pencil drawings?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am writing my resume, I do average pencil drawing & documenting tags like "developer", "photographer". In this way I want to tag as "pencil drawing artist" please help with phrase this in a better way.

Comment: Well, if you do "average" pencil drawing then I guess you're a *mediocre* artist.

Comment: You’d should call yourself a *pencil artist*.   A sketch artist is one typically employed by the police to render an image of a suspect from a witness’s verbal description.

Comment: just a piece of advice - don't call yourself average on your own resume. Find a way to be honest but effective.

Comment: Related question = https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414137/need-a-single-word-term-for-one-who-draws

Answer (score 3):

You could be a [sketcher](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sketch?s=t).

A sketch is:

> a simply or hastily executed drawing or painting, especially a preliminary one, giving the essential features without the details.

(Note: do *not* use "sketchy", as it has a negative connotation, implying incomplete or insufficient - emphasizing the "hastily executed" and "without the details" parts.)