# Need a single-word term for "an artist who produces drawings"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

All my life I've been looking for a single word in English to describe *someone who draws*.  It would be the equivalent of "a painter", or "a ceramicist", or "a sculptor".

"Draftsman" has a technical slant to it.
"Illustrator" implies that the drawing accompanies text or implies a particular meaning.

A "Drawer" is part of a piece of furniture.

Haven't found anyone on either side of the Atlantic who has a good answer.

**Sample sentence:**

Hello, everybody! My name is Emily and I am a ______________ (someone who draws pictures, as in produces drawings as an art form).

Comment: Hello, Emily. 'Painter' also means a rope used to tie up a boat. (Though this is actually a different word, a homograph.) If you're happy to carry on using 'painter' to mean 'one who paints', why can't 'drawer' be used to mean 'one who draws'? Have you checked in a dictionary?

Comment: **/drɔr/** the sliding, box-like open container that is found in cabinets, wardrobes, and chests. **/drɔ ər/** for the person who draws. Listen to the pronunciations here: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drawer. Maybe this is yet another British English versus American English difference... (I pronounce the name of the artist differently from the piece of furniture)   However, [there are lots of online dictionaries](http://www.yourdictionary.com/drawer) that define "drawer" as a person who draws.

Comment: Well, if I describe Vincent Van Gough as a painter, I don't think there's much risk of someone thinking that I've got a piece of rope with a famous name. And yes, it did occur to me to look in a dictionary for this - when I was about 10. Most dictionaries describe a "drawer" with the following definitions: a boxlike compartment, underpants, one who takes money from a bank account, and someone who draws.  My entire point is that NO ONE ACTUALLY uses the word "draw-er" as one who draws.  The pronunciation alone is unwieldy and causes one to say it with an exaggerated Southern (USA) accent.

Comment: Again, folks - Please imagine an introduction in which you describe what you do.  But you don't work with paint, and you aren't a composer, or a singer, or a sculptor, or a playwright.  You draw pictures.  Is it really the best thing to say, "I am a drawer."  I KNOW the dictionary states that "drawer" is correct (way down in the list of definitions), but my ORIGINAL POINT is that "drawer" isn't a great term for this usage.  Was hoping for a more extensive vocabulary.  Any Britons here?  Actually, any drawers here?

Comment: Isn't the author referring to 'drawing cash' from bank/ ATM etc.?  Or one who draws a cheque (AE, check)?

Comment: Would you give more about why you're limited to one word? Two words would give you many analogies to *musical artist* or *performance artist* or *ceramic artist* (better than *ceramicist* IMO) - *line artist*, *pen artist*, or even *ballpoint artist* could work, depending on your technique or tool. Otherwise, I can only think of process-based words (*designer*, *penciller*), since in many media drawing is used as part of a design process.

Comment: @RamPillai no,  the question is not about a drawer as in a drawer from a bank, it is about someone who draws (pictures and the like) as an art form.

Comment: Even if one decides to use _drawer_ as a personal agentive, there's the instrumental _drawer_ as in _kitchen drawer_ to compete with. And then there's the problem of pronunciation. To be distinguished from /dror/ as in _kitchen drawer_, one would  have to pronounce the personal agentive _drawer_ with two syllables as /'drɔər/ like _cutters of wood and drawers of water_.

Comment: The problem is that you're looking for an occupational term without the connotations of common paying occupations, hence the exclusion of illustrator and draughtsman (although I suggest "draught-artist" as a credible term, and the etymology of draught is related to draw).

Comment: Interesting view on **illustrator**. If someone mentioned to me they are an **illustrator**, my immediate impression is they draw.

Comment: You know those guys in old "Wild West" movies?  The one who draws his six-gun from his holster faster than anyone else:  Now **that's** a "drawer".

Comment: Hi; I've updated your title to better match the requirements you put in the question body.

Comment: I think the OP @EmilyCanter has moved on and perhaps doesnt even care anymore, or maybe she has found a word other than drawer (draw-er). If she has, it would be fantastic if she visited us and let us know, and maybe even wrote an answer for 500 points. (This comment assumes Emily is a female and doesnt mind traditional pronouns.)

Comment: Yeah , drawer can easily go the way of 'rural juror'. think, if E drew 'rural jurors' E could be a 'rural juror drawer.' My gosh,,,, get the tobacco out of your mouth and speak. :)

Comment: I will simply say ***I draw***. It encompasses everything and anything.

Comment: yes, @Jalene Hi Im Emily and I draw for a living'. I have thought of that. But is 'draw' unambiguous here? I mean, draw as in draw pictures or as in draw a gun. But hey I think you could write this as answer, with more detail. I like it.

Comment: @green_ideas ***My name is Emily and I draw.*** I think few will associate that with **draw a gun**? I personally feel that ***I draw*** is very empowering. Perhaps the chances of being interpreted as **draw a gun** will depend on the situation? If is in a riot, a criminal scenario, or maybe a law enforcer trying to inject some sense of humour in their self introduction...

Comment: @Jalene I like that answer but I cannot award the 500-point bounty to that answer unless you (or someone else) writes an answer. For you, all you need to do is copy and paste your comments regarding "I draw" as an answer.

Comment: why dont you use 'artist'. I have given my answer below.

Comment: You specifically ask for a single word and then accept "I draw"?! Not so good with the numbers?

Answer (score 10):

I believe, the only generic apt term would be **drawing artist** which isn't a single word. (You can hyphenate as *drawing-artist* if you really want to use a single word). Many drawing art and job websites use this term. There are more specific terms like *pencil artist, portrait drawing artist* etc. also.

As already mentioned, the only generic single word is *drawer* but it is not that useful to use this term for one who draws. Additionally, it depends on what you draw and on your occupation/art etc. so there isn't a generic and useful single word. There are even *cartoonists* who are technically a drawing artist.

The reason why the term *drawer* is not common like *painter* and *sculptor* might be that painting and sculpting were prominent and established art forms in the history and there were popular and influential artists of this art form; thus there are generic and common single word terms as painter and sculptor for the artists. Drawing was more like a technical occupation throughout the history as in draftsmanship where there are specialties like architectural drafters, mechanical drafters etc. In art, it was rather an artistic practice than an established art form so we could say that a painter is/was a drawer already. Traditional drawings were simple compared to some modern drawing forms where they may look like a work between drawing and painting; and drawing has become a more established art form with more categories, online platforms, digital art softwares and creative works in recent history.

---

Beside online platforms, I've found the term *drawing artist* used in some art books about drawing:

From *Drawing* by Daniel Marcus Mendelowitz (1967):

> To illustrate the extent to which color has served the **drawing artist**, sixteen of the 314 master drawings in this book have been reproduced in full color.

From *Drawing media & techniques* by Joseph A. Gatto (1987):

> The endless combinations of media and surfaces make it virtually impossible to explore the complete spectrum. Yet non-traditional media are not entirely different from traditional drawing media. Both offer broad artistic challenges, fresh with each drawing you begin. Both should be experienced to enable you to achieve your greatest potential as a **drawing artist**.

From *Contemporary Drawing: Key Concepts and Techniques*
by Margaret Davidson (2011):

> The first concept discussed in the chapters that follow is the **drawing artist**'s deliberate choice of surface. What the surface is determines the nature of the mark. Furthermore, a focus on both the surface and the mark and the relationship between the two is one of hallmarks of contemporary drawing, and one of the most fundamental abstract issues **drawing artists** deal with.

<sub>Note: The author uses the term throughout the book and calls herself a *drawing artist* also.</sub>

Comment: Sometimes two words are *way* better than one.

Comment: I think you're right about the reason for this. Until fairly recently drawing was a part of the preparation for painting, sculpture, tapestry, and other more highly-valued artistic practices, rather than an artistic end in itself. There's a lack of words for people who practice other forms like video art; photographer and printmaker are single-word names, but those names don't specifically refer to art practice any more than "drawer" does.

Comment: Sorry, but drawing artist is not a thing. In all my days of museum- and gallery-going, not to mention reading art books, I have never seen that.

Comment: @Lambie: Yes, it is not an established art term or a dictionary term like _painter_ and _sculptor_ and I've explained some of the reasons already. _Drawing artist_ became a more popular term where drawing became a more established art form and with the online platforms. It is also an approach to find a generic term with the use of the established term "artist".

Comment: well +1 from me. And I am not the OP, so any reasonable compound is okay by me. Still, the OP balks at drawer, and *Hello, I am a drawing artist*, hmm, sounds vaguely like *Hello, I am a growing tree*. I dunno. Really like the references.

Comment: @ermanen if drawing artist were on the drawing board here, I would have heard it in my perambulations in the world of art. Online platform usage is really not relevant. It may be in the dictionary, it may be in some pedagogical work (Ms. Davidson) because she ain't no writer. The first concept discussed in the chapters that follow is the artist's deliberate choice of **drawing** surface.

Comment: I like "pencil artist" best.

Answer (score 7):

Drawer

[Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drawer) definition 3

> A person who produces a drawing or design.

Examples

> ‘The fact that these three are expert drawers and painters doesn't hurt either.’
>
> ‘The drawer's signature will be executed just above it.’
>
> ‘Jordy had always been a good drawer, he could draw trees amazingly.’
>
> ‘You've spoken about being a drawer, painter, writer too, as well as composer.’

Comment: I've upvoted because it's the only acceptable answer, but it's worth pointing out that the piece of furniture which the OP mentions is pronounced differently from the name of a person who draws.

Comment: Before stating that "drawer" IS the best possible term, try saying to yourself - as though in an introduction including your hobby - "I am a drawer".  Then I think you'll see the problem.  For one thing, simply saying that you're an "artist" is an uncomfortably pretentious declaration.  Being termed "artist" is what others are to say ABOUT a person.  The person doesn't usually say it of himself. And IN WHAT ART they participate?  Bernstein, Picasso, Fellini, and Michael Jackson were ALL "artists".

Comment: Dear @Mari-LouA The bounty is serious as stated. As for line in question, it was (my)  user error. Any efforts or suggestions to answer the question will be greatly appreciated. Peace out.

Comment: This is the best answer, because it succeeds in answering the question within requirements - a question that has its problems, because why would you insist on using a single word, if several two word phrases do a much better job? English is full of examples where two or more words are required or the best solution - something that took some getting used to for myself as well, coming from a language that allows stringing words together into single new words.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: are they pronounced differently in all dialects of English? It's certainly true in RP, where the furniture *drawer* is pronounced like *draw*, and the artist *drawer* should be pronounced like *drora*. And it's true in many American dialects, as well. But I'm pretty sure that in some American dialects, they're homonyms.

Comment: @PeterShor  I wouldn't have guessed that the two meanings had an identical pronunciation. However, in some dialects, there is a difference in pronunciation,  and that  is worth mentioning.

Comment: This is English Language and **Usage**; calling a person who draws a drawer might even be insulting. Who would say that?? Dictionaries don't show usage. My name is Emily and I am **an artist** who draws [x].

Comment: A drawer as in a draw-er, not a drawer (pronounced different(ly)) in US, all dialects as far as I know. Except maybe southern drawl (lol), where they drawl everything. (even they dont draw)

Answer (score 5):

Well I am no expert and late to this question - so if it has been offered and I missed it sorry - but I call one who draws a sketch artists or a sketcher.  Works for me as drawer is to easily confused and breaks the stream of consciousness for the reader when used in context of one who draws.  This answer may be a little sketchy ;>.

Comment: Not every drawing is a sketch.

Comment: @KillingTime, if they're not a sketcher or sketch-artist (because that conveys a certain roughness or shoddiness) then the appropriate term is surely drafter or draught-artist?

Comment: @Steve drafting, sketching and drawing are different disciplines of art. Sketching can be the step before actual drawing but drawing is not the same as sketching.

Answer (score 3):

The OP in a comment said

> Before stating that "drawer" IS the best possible term, try saying to yourself - as though in an introduction including your hobby - "I am a drawer". Then I think you'll see the problem. For one thing, simply saying that you're an "artist" is an uncomfortably pretentious declaration. Being termed "artist" is what others are to say ABOUT a person. The person doesn't usually say it of himself. And IN WHAT ART they participate? Bernstein, Picasso, Fellini, and Michael Jackson were ALL "artists".

First, it's obvious, according to dictionaries, that *drawer* IS the right word.  I agree it sounds strange to my ears, but that doesn't make it incorrect.  For some reason it doesn't seem to be in common usage.  So let's start using it, & correct this oversight.

Second, there's nothing pretentious about calling yourself an artist if you are one, any more than calling yourself a musician, an athlete, a writer, or a politician is pretentious.  If you feel self-conscious about calling yourself an artist, either gain some self-esteem to be comfortable about who you are & what you do, or change careers/hobbies.

Comment: This is more of a comment and not an answer per se. Please see the tour - this isn't a forum site.

Comment: Saying "I am an artist" is not pretentious at all, if you really are one. For pete's sake. Political correctness may have its place but not here. That said no one actually uses drawer in the art world, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Although many dictionaries define 'drawer' as 'someone who draws pictures', I understand the OP's frustration when trying to use it as in her introduction. The culprit that makes it sound unnatural is in part the fact that such usage is not very idiomatic, and in part the fact that the meaning of 'drawer' is not specific enough to convey the exact meaning she wants to get across.

Since she wants a single-word term for "someone who draws pictures, as in produces drawings as an art form", I'd suggest ***picture-drawer***:

> *Hello, everybody! My name is Emily and I am a **picture-drawer**.*

By adding ***picture-*** with a hyphen, you could make the term  a single word that's specific enough to use in introductions.

There are [many examples of "a picture drawer" on Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_koKR818KR818&biw=1067&bih=526&tbs=bkt%3Ab&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQQf7IMibQDOO8uxjRAWLONU0MwUQ%3A1576106462182&ei=3nnxXcXYCpn_wAOu96OoDw&q=%22a%20picture%20drawer%22&oq=%22a%20picture%20drawer%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12432.12766.0.13374.2.2.0.0.0.0.102.202.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.KXH0IIJ_jKE) with or without the hyphen.

Comment: Hello, everybody! My name is Emily, I just travelled here from 1874, and I am a picture-drawer.

Comment: @green_ideas Well, the term 'picture drawer' is not exactly obsolete, as shown in this Ngram: (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+picture+drawer&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20picture%20drawer%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20picture%20drawer%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I think only that the OP (Emily) would probably balk at adding something to the word 'draw-er', which she obviously dislikes. So, it is harder,or at least more drawn out) to say I am a picture-drawer than I am a drawer (draw-er).

Answer (score 2):

The word is: sketcher

He was a brilliant sketcher and in his journeys made some clever and humorous pencil drawings of scenes which took place on the road.

Hello, everybody! My name is Emily and I am a sketcher.

Comment: A sketch is a kind of drawing. Usually done rather fast.

Comment: @Lambie but this word defines it correctly though.

Answer (score 1):

I propose the conception of a new word. **Drawing** inspiration from my native language *Danish*, we have the word 'tegner', having the sole meaning of "one who draws". The word is created from the noun 'tegn', which means 'sign'. Too "at tegne" is a verb and means "To draw". So what my immediate proposal would thus be: 'Signager'. But not really. Contemplating the above information might bring the desired results on your part.

Comment: A *signager* sounds to me like somebody who designs signboards, logos, and so forth.

Comment: How is one meant to pronounce *signager*? Can you add the proposed (English) pronunciation in an readable format, preferably IPA?

Comment: @green_ideas: A *signager* would be one who produces [*signage*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signage).  It's pronounced like *signage* with an *-er* stuck on the end. That would be /ˈsaɪnɪdʒə/ in British English and /ˈsaɪnɪdʒər/ in American English. And it is a terrible choice of word for somebody who draws pictures.

Answer (score 1):

> **I Draw**
>
> *Hello, everybody! My name is Emily and* **I draw.**

My thought is a ceramist has to use ceramic as a medium to be called a ceramist. A painter has to use paint to be called a painter. Or rather, they can be defined by the medium they chose to work with. Hence, there is a *proper term* for them.

A person who draws can draw with anything and on anything and about anything. Simply by saying ***I draw*** is empowering. It encompasses everything and anything.

Comment: I would also like to add that adding the word *artist* is superfluous. *I draw* by itself means *I am an artist* and *I am an artist who draws*.

Comment: I am an artist who paints x; I am an artist who sculpts y.Just saying: I draw or I paint is very weak, marketing-wise.

Comment: I personally find adding the word artist is not necessary. I draw and I paint has already demonstrated I am an artist. Happy Holidays btw! Merry Christmas!

Comment: @green_ideas Thank you! because of the bounty, I got a new hat and added an extra digit for the new year! Off to a bountiful 2020!

Answer (score 1):

The United States Department of Labor uses the term "Illustrator" as a subtype of Fine Artist:

[27-1013.00 - Fine Artists, Including Painters, Sculptors, and Illustrators](https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/27-1013.00)

> Create original artwork using any of a wide variety of media and techniques.
>
> Sample of reported job titles: Artist, Automotive Artist, Blacksmith, Fine Artist, Ice Carver, Illustrator, Muralist, Painter, Portrait Artist, Sculptor

Answer (score 1):

People have used

> pencil artist,
>   pen artist,
>   pen and pencil artist,

Certainly, *pen and pencil artist* conveys the ideal of somebody who draws with different media, even if it isn't a complete list of all possible drawing media.

Comment: I do not see how this is an answer, rather than a comment about other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it counts as a "single-word", but I'd use

> visual artist

in your example sentence.

Comment: a compound word can indeed be written with a space.

Answer (score 0):

1) Hello, my name is Emily and **I am an artist** **who draws** [x.]

That is how to say this in English.

For example:

He is an **artist who draws, paints and sculpts the Native American Indian in a rustic impressionistic style.**

[enter link description here](http://buffalobullhowling.com/bio.html)

2) Hello, my name is Emily and I do drawings of [whatever].

like this:

The obvious crowd pleaser in the show is *The Great Travelling Art Exhibition* by British artist Ben Long’s DVD of his drawings in the dust on the backs of delivery vans parked in the car park at Covent Garden Markets in London. **He does drawings of horses, little girls with puppy dogs, blue finches, Spitfire fighters – all the kinds of things people like to see done in well executed drawings**.

[do drawings](http://theartlife.com.au/2004/not-fake-actually-real/)

The word artist in English can be further qualified. There is no good word for a person who only draws (pencil or charcoal) pictures of stuff.

Even languages that have words like **dessinateur** or **dibujante**, French and Spanish respectively, require clarification in context. It is not obvious on their face that these words refer to art(istic) drawing.

So, English is not the only language that doesn't have a good noun for the person who does drawings. And I don't think it's worth belaboring this point further.

However, please note this description of who was probably the greatest artist of all times: Michelangelo. Below is a review of a show of his drawings. They say draftsman and designer but also artist collocated with the word drawing.

Here is one art journal (from Boston University) describes the MET show of his works:

> The Metropolitan Museum of Art’s wide-ranging exhibition
>   “Michelangelo: Divine Draftsman & Designer” examines the artistic
>   production and development of the Renaissance master through his
>   drawings. The exhibit is a result of the recent scholarly interest in
>   drawings and their importance within the artistic process. [...] 200
>   works of art in diverse media: sculpture, paintings, architectural
>   models, and drawings. On view are 133 drawings by Michelangelo, from
>   fifty public and private collections in the United States and Europe,
>   including studies of anatomy, preparatory sketches, as well as highly
>   finished compositions. The exhibition celebrates Michelangelo as a
>   **disegnatore**, draftsman, and demonstrates his extensive use of **disegno**, drawing, from his early days in Florence until his death in Rome.
>
> [...]
>
> **Through his drawings**, the exhibition effectively displays **Michelangelo’s versatility as an artist** as the works relate to all the artistic fields in which he was active. Beyond that, the exhibit
>   shows him not as **a solitary artist**, but rather as one operating
>   within a greater artistic network of patrons and artists.

[draftsman and designer](https://www.bu.edu/sequitur/2018/09/13/michelangelo-divine-draftsman-designer/)